# Only part of unicode is replacing in python.Don't understand why

Tags: python, string, unicode, replace

```
subject = page.select('div.container h1')
subject = [x.text.replace('2015', '')for x in subject] 
print subject



[u'\u20132016 Art Courses']# This is the code after.
[u'2015\u20132016 Art Courses']#This is the code before.
subject = [x.text.replace('20132016', '')for x in subject]
```

When I try to change the .replace to '20132016' it just prints out
    [u'2015\u20132016 Art Courses']

would anyone know how to get rid of the 20132016 as well as the word
courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u2013` is a unicode symbol `en dash`. Check [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) for example.

So to get rid of all but Art you need to replace it like this:

```
>>> a = u'2015\u20132016 Art Courses'
>>> a.replace(u'2015\u20132016', '').replace('Courses', '').strip()
u'Art'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the characters "2013" in your string. You have a single character, unicode 2013, ie "–", an en dash. You need to replace that character.

```
x.text.replace(/u'u20132016', '') for x in subject]
```